# If $\mathcal A$ is diagonalizable, determine $\mathcal S$ and $\Lambda$ such that $\mathcal A=\mathcal S\Lambda\mathcal S^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\mathcal A=\pmatrix{-5.25&-4.125&8.25\\-15&-0.5&15\\-4.75&-0.375&7.75}$$

If $\mathcal A$ is diagonalizable, determine $\mathcal S$ and $\Lambda$ such that $\mathcal A=\mathcal S\Lambda\mathcal S^{-1}$

So far I have calculated $det(\lambda I-\mathcal A)=0$

and ended up with:

$$\lambda^3-2\lambda^2-59.005\lambda+170.813=0$$

Now I'm stuck.....how do I find the eigenvalues from this??  Any help would be great appreciated!  :)

The ultimate goal of this question is to find $\mathcal S$ and $\Lambda$.

This is what I have found using $\lambda_1=3$, $\lambda_2=7$ and $\lambda_3=-8$:

$$\mathcal S=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\1&1&0}$$

$$\Lambda=\pmatrix{3&0&0\\0&7&0\\0&0&-8}$$

But when I try to produce $\mathcal S^{-1}$ I get a matrix of infinities!!  Is it possible for someone to explain this??  It is greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: I am afraid that you have a wrong calculation. And with `maple` the eigenvalues are $3,7,-8$. Try again?

Comment: @eccstartup~ is there a way to do this in Matlab?  I don't use Maple.  I will however, try by hand again.  I'm working on two problems using the same type of calculation and both are very strange.

Comment: search `det` for determinant in the help page. And search `eigenvalues`. I think they can help you solve this. You may like to google with a `MATLAB` keyword prefix.

Comment: @eccstartup~ Thank you so much for your help.  I will try by hand and with Matlab.

Comment: @Lanae: Did you notice any strangeness with the diagonalization (eigenvectors and matrix $P$) as I think that is really the purpose of this exercise. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti~ I haven't calculated $\mathcal S$ or $\Lambda$ yet, so I will get back to you.  I'm working on 10 problems all at once.  A little overwhelming!!

Comment: @Amzoti~ I calculated $\mathcal S$ and $\Lambda$, please see above.  I have a problem with $\mathcal S^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, your $S$ is singular to begin with, but that is not what I recall from the calculations I did. Like I said, this exercise is intended to teach you about numerical precision, rounding, ill-conditioned matrices and the like and it looks like you are on the path! I get a radically different S and there is no way those can be your eigenvectors for this matrix. How did you calculate those? How did you get a column of zeros as an eigenvector (is that allowed)? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti~ I calculated my eigenvalues. Then using det($\lambda I-A)=0$ calculated the eigenvector for each eigenvalue.  $\mathcal S$ is the matrix of the eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is the matrix of diagonal $\lambda$s. I used an LU decomposition in Matlab to get the U to use as my RREF form because by hand its impossible.

Comment: @Lanae: There must be errors in the eigenvector calculations, but that is the bulk of this question and the answer was already accepted for the CP. Yes, I know where the matrices come from :-), but am saying that they are not correct - something went wrong somehow in calcs.

Comment: @Amzoti~How can I change this to get some help?  The answer that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\lambda}^{3}- 2{\lambda}^{2}- 59\lambda+168=0$

I did it with maple.

Comment: ~ I used Matlab and got the same solution and the eigenvalues for two of the problems that I'm working on.  Again, thank you so much for your help.